# Movie set on a gunship on an asteroid: lone man fires rounds into space

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm not sure the actor. But this movie takes place in a small gun ship dug into a small crevice on a small asteroid deep in space. One man alone fires rounds into deep space towards coordinates given to him by radio transmission. It shows him with a guitar and other things he does to stay occupied while on this vessel. The movie ends with him firing into space after noticing something on his radar. But failing, he then realizes they have found his asteroid and are coming aboard. Before they open his hatch, he figures suicide is better than getting abducted. He shoots himself and then. Credits...

Comment: Maybe *Sniper 470*?

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [*Sniper 470*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0358703/)

According to the description [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0358703/reviews):

> The Gunner sits in his pod and waits, millions of miles away from
>   Earth. This is Sniper 470. His task is to destroy convoys of ships
>   that cross the Trojan Asteroid Belt, and, with a little luck, survive.

So there’s a gunner on an asteroid.

He is quite [isolated](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0358703/reviews):

> Seperated [sic] from family, love, even his orders are from a
>   computerised voice. He can’t see his friends die, can’t offer them
>   comfort, only watch their names scroll by on a computer screen.

I can’t find a reference for it, but he does seem to shoot himself in the end. Oh, and there’s definitely a guitar.